# Align submit with border-bottom on input buttons on a form

Tags: css, forms

I was studing this webpage https://dailylogochallenge.com/

And I was trying to recreate the form input buttons. What fixes it on that page is using

```
*, *:before, *:after{
    box-sizing: inherit;
}
```

I tried on my page but I couldn't come up with the solution.

HTML:

```
<form action="">
   <input type="text" name="firstname" value="First Name">
   <input type="text" name="email" value="Email">
   <input type="submit" value="Get Started today">
</form>
```

CSS

```
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

form{
    margin-top: 30px;
}

form input{
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    border-bottom: 10px solid black;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 0 20px 0 0;
    font-size: 1.05rem;
    font-weight: 700;
    height: 60px;
}


input[type="submit"]{
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    color: white;
    background-color: black;
    height: 60px;
    padding: 0 20px;
    box-shadow: 5px 10px 30px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}

*:before, *:after{
    box-sizing: inherit;
}
```

Comment: Your style sheet does not set `* { box-sizing: inherit; }` like the referenced website does. You're only setting it to the *:before and *:after pseudo elements

Comment: You're right, but it still didn't change anything, idk if there's some other trick used that I can't pinpoint... Maybe it has to do with every input and submit button being inside a div, but there's so much nesting that who knows...